# Convert string that contain square brackets and double quote to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

i want to convert this string

```
["A", "B"]
```

to a array with value like this

```
arr[0] // A
arr[1] // B
```

Comment: Since your string appears to be valid JSON: `JSON.parse(yourString)`

Comment: thank you, it works. i will answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not a string, it's an array, if you want parse it with JSON.parse you should have a right JSON format, a right format of your string should be like this :

```
'{"yourArray":["A","B"]}'
```

You have just to copy it inside a variable, if you use JS your solution should be like this :

```
let arr = ["A","B"];
console.log(arr[0],arr[1]) //  A, B .
```

Comment: *"Your input is not a string, it's an array, "* You cannot say that without knowing the context. `["A", "B"]` could be the response of an HTTP request.

Comment: Ensure that you have a right JSON format, then parse it with JSON.parse(yourString);

Comment: `["A", "B"]`, as it is, is valid JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling you parse it with response.json()? if you already do this, you can access directly to your array.

Comment: I didn't ask the question. I just commented on your answer.

Comment: No problem you welcome, yes you was right, it's a valid json format, json can be an array and I forgot this. so we can access directly to our array after all the json method on the response object.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = JSON.parse(myString);

console.log(arr[0]) // A
console.log(arr[1]) // B
```

Comment: In your example `myString` is not a string. The code will not work.

Comment: That particular example is valid JSON, yes

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving this as a string, then you can use the JSON.parse() method to turn this into an array.

```
var parsedArray = JSON.parse(recievedArray);
console.log(parsedArray);
```

That will turn you're stringified array into an array you can actually use.  If you want to see why you can't just use the array you got, use

```
console.log(recievedArray.split('');
```

You'll see how what you really have is one big string.  Hope this helps.